# SQL Order of execution when DISTINCT and AVG are present in the same SELECT statement

Tags: sql, oracle, distinct, average

I'm using Oracle 11g. In what order will this SQL statement be "parsed"?

Assuming there are many duplicate values in col2:

```
SELECT DISTINCT col1, AVG(col2)
FROM table1
GROUP BY col1
```

Will it:
1. remove all the duplicate `col1`-`col2` data combination, and then do an average on `col2` on this reduced resultset, OR
2. do an aggregate average on `col2` first, and then do a distinct on this resultset?

Comment: Since you do `GROUP BY col1`, `DISTINCT` is redundant - the result is already distinct.

Comment: Expanding on jarlh's comment: GROUP BY is processed before SELECT. So you can't change this example to transform it into one where the question is not moot. The question is moot no matter how you rewrite the query - the GROUP BY is processed first, and only GROUP BY columns can be included in SELECT (at which point they are already DISTINCT).

Comment: @jarlh When i group by on Col1, isnt it only grouping by col1? So in this case col2 still can have multiple duplicates in it right? My question was, will having DISTINCT still on the SELECT have any impact on the duplicates WITHIN col2. Thanks for checking!

Comment: I think you meant *processed* or *executed* instead of *parsed*.  And for what it's worth, I don't think it would have been very hard for you to setup a little test scenario to verify the behavior yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An exampe should be self-explanatory:

```
SQL> create table testDistinct (col1, col2) as(
  2    select 1, 100 from dual union all
  3    select 1, 10  from dual union all
  4    select 1, 10  from dual union all
  5    select 2, 50  from dual union all
  6    select 3, 1   from dual union all
  7    select 3, 100 from dual
  8  );

Table created.

SQL> select col1, avg(col2)
  2  from testDistinct
  3  group by col1;

      COL1  AVG(COL2)
---------- ----------
         1         40
         2         50
         3       50,5

SQL> select DISTINCT col1, avg(col2)
  2  from testDistinct
  3  group by col1;

      COL1  AVG(COL2)
---------- ----------
         1         40
         2         50
         3       50,5
```

Applying the GROUP over the result of a DISTINCT gives:

```
SQL> select col1, avg(col2)
  2  from (
  3      select DISTINCT col1, col2
  4      from testDistinct
  5  )
  6  group by col1;

      COL1  AVG(COL2)
---------- ----------
         1         55
         2         50
         3       50,5
```

Comment: Thanks! So this does mean that the DISTINCT has no meaning here.

Comment: The `DISTINCT` has no meaning in your query, although I'm not sure if Oracle is smart enough to optimize it away.